# Using intellij idea merge as default merge tool in hg

Tags: intellij-idea, merge, mercurial

So, i've found this page [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/running-intellij-idea-as-a-diff-or-merge-command-line-tool.html?origin=old_help#d693010e136), showing how to use intellij's idea merge and diff from command line, and i'm trying to set it as a default for hg.
However, i still have some problems when merging branches (many files):

- If hg merge is called while there's no idea instance running, it starts a new instance, show the diff, wait for my response (click on apply / abort). After that, it proceeds to the next file, and do the same. File by file. Works pretty well, but is also veery slow (since it needs to start a new instance every time). Also, as said, there must be no idea instance running, to do that.
- If hg merge is called while an idea instance is running, it shows the first diff window, but at the same time starts to merge all other files... This end up in a lot of pop-ups of "file not found" on idea, pointing to tmp files (of .other and .original).
  Does anybody know how to do that in a usable way? hg merge using idea merge as default ?
  Here's my .hgrc file: 
   `[ui]
  merge=idea
  [merge-tools]
  idea =
  idea.gui = True
  idea.args = merge $local $base $other $output
  idea.priority = 1000
  idea.premerge = False`

  Sorry for the bad english, and thanks to all in advance

Answer (score 4):

Hi here are the settings I used successfully.

```
[ui]
merge=idea

[merge-tools]
idea.args = merge $local $other $base $output
```

Also ensure that `idea` is on the path.

My references are the [mercurial MergeToolConfiguration](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration) and [Merging files using IntelliJ IDEA as a command line tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/running-intellij-idea-as-a-diff-or-merge-command-line-tool.html#d739193e209).

Answer (score 2):

Idea does not wait, but gives return too early. A good way to solve this problem is to get mercurial to prompt you.

By setting this configuration in the .hgrc

```
idea.check = prompt
```

Mercurial will ask for confirmation on each file. You must finish the merge in Idea before clicking "Yes" on the confirmation box.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but it was the only result at Google, so I decided to leave an answer for later visitors.

Comment: Not sure from where you got this, but this really made my day after struggling with Merge error: "Error showing merge: Can't find file:" for hours because of that "return too early" thingy. Thank you, mate, thank you! :))

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's an IntelliJ or Mercurial change, but the answer about using:

```
idea.check = prompt
```

does not seem to work anymore.
On opening, IntelliJ tells me it can't find one of the files in /var/folders/nd/xxxxx.

This "check" element is not even present in [the doc](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration) as of writing.

I was not yet able to verify any workaround, as I need to encounter another merge conflict to verify that, but modifying the idea script to force user input before exiting could be a way.